# repeating coding using input "y" or "n"

Tags: python, while-loop

I have figured out how to repeat my code if the user types in a letter but I don't know how to make the code stop if the user inputs "n"

```
repeat_code = True
while repeat_code:
    base = int(input("Enter base: "))
    height = int(input("Enter height: "))
    side1 = int(input("Enter side 1:  "))
    side2 = int(input("Enter side 2:  "))
    side3 = int(input("Enter side 3:  "))
    area = find_area(base,height)
    ftype = find_type(side1,side2,side3)
    print('This %s triangle has area %.2f' % (ftype, 
    area))
    user_input = input("Have another go?")
    if repeat_code = user_input !="y"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement at the end there is invalid syntax, so I'm not entirely sure what you intended to do with that `if` unfortunately. But the good news is, your problem is easily solvable by removing the `if` and flipping the operator in that statement. That way, the result of `user_input == "k"` (instead of `user_input != "k"`, which you currently have) will be assigned to `repeat_code`. So if `user_input == "k"`, then `repeat_code` will be `True`, and thus when the `while` loop condition is checked after that last line, it will be `True`, and the code will repeat. If `user_input != "k"`, then `repeat_code` will be `False`, meaning the loop condition will evaluate to `False`, which will end the loop.